# JPA Inner and outer Join

Tags: jpa

I want to get list of events using following query.

I am able to do it through normal query at database level . But I am strugulling when writing JPA query.

Request you all to help me in writing JPA query.

```
select e.id  from event e 
                left outer join 
                (sub_portfolio s inner join 
                (portfolio P inner join ACADEMY a on p.academy_id=a.id) on s.portfolio_id=p.id) 
                on e.sub_portfolio_id=s.id
```

Comment: what are those brackets doing in join clauses? remove them, and put the ON with the join

Comment: If you are selecting only the ID from Event entity without using any WHERE clause, what's the need of the JOINs used?